# Проблема с node-fetch

Tags: node.js, axios

мне необходимо отправить запрос на одну апишку и у меня проблемы, библиотка ловит socket hang up, потому что сервер долго отвечает. Пробовал уже делать и на axios и нативном http, но не работает всё равно. Код:

```js
require('node-fetch')(`https://pelevin.gpt.dobro.ai/generate/`,{
method: 'POST',
body: JSON.stringify({prompt:"сыр",length:30})
}).then(x => x.json()).then(console.log)


require('axios').post("https://pelevin.gpt.dobro.ai/generate/", {
body: JSON.stringify({
    prompt: "сыр",
   length:30

  })
gzip:true 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что что-то там такое настроено, фильтрующее по содержимому заголовка `User-Agent`.

```
const { default: fetch } = require('node-fetch');
const { default: axios } = require('axios');

const url = 'https://pelevin.gpt.dobro.ai/generate/';
const requestBody = JSON.stringify({ prompt: 'мохнатый сыр', length: 50 });
const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0';

(async () => {
  try {
    const p1 = fetch(
      url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: requestBody,
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': userAgent
        }
      }
    ).then((r) => r.json());

    const p2 = axios.post(
      url, requestBody, {
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': userAgent
        }
      }
    );

    const [data1, { data: data2 }] = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);
    console.log(data1);
    console.log(data2);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

```bsh
$ node src/pelevin-ai-generate/index.js 
{
  replies: [
    '. И вот появилась сцена, на которой убивали Эйфелеву башню. Вы можете сказать, что это не совсем так. Эйфелева башня действительно была убита. Но произошло это совсем не так, как описано в учебнике.',
    ', притащенный из Европы и нанизанный на бечевку, передал профессору Платонову Алексей Александрович, с которым дядя Митяй поделился историей с чаем.',
    'ный пирожок и обсосать его в сухой пипе». Или это в ресторанах, где каждый раз под новый гриль рассаживают по разным столикам. А иногда это случается в пивнушках на Привозе.'
  ]
}
{
  replies: [
    ' посыпают измельченным сухим укропом. Сверху украшают сливами, половинками яйца и подают к столу. Блюдо подают охлажденным.',
    '», изучаю в Европе народность китов. Я купил книгу о своем имидже: «Bang Bang»[ 1 - «Удар по яйцам».',
    '? Она ведь даже в песенке, которую пела, как его… Ну, у Люси Тейлор, наверное, раньше не было… Впрочем, и до Люси Тейлор тоже. А вообще, все они какие-то придурочные.'
  ]
}
```